# How to create "scrolling headlines" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

There is a heading and some text with an image under that heading. The text with that image should scroll vertically upwards. where as the heading should change according to the text. For example, lets say I have a news headline

1. JAPAN EarthQuake: Some Description about Japan Disaster with an image
2. India Politics: Some latets news about Indian Politics with an image

etc

I need a script which can first show JAPAN EarthQuake heading and under it, the desription with image will scroll upwards. Once the scroll is complete or after some time, it will change the heading to  India Politics and show its description with its image under it which will again scroll upwards.

How can I achieve this using JavaScript? Any available script online anywhere or some demo?

Comment: Obviously its a JavaScript question (Stack Overflow has tags), can your title reflect a *summary* of your question?

Answer (score 1):

Used this one before

[Animated Scroll](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html)

Dead easy to use and set up using ul > li tags

Comment: Thanks for that link BUT that does not only the scrolling part. I would like to see a headline changer as well

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript animations are notoriously difficult to perform in a cross browser. I would take a look at using a framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) in order to perform them.

Look for the animate() method.

Comment: As of now I have something like this

`Put my Static Heading here in a table cell

<td width="175"><marquee onMouseover="this.stop()" onMouseout="this.start()" direction = up loop="infinite" scrollamount="2"><table width="183" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0">

Put the image and description here`

Now how do I edit this? I am new to Js or Jquery for that matter. So, if someone can guide me with some examples, please?